# CompletableFuture.allOff completes even if one CompletableFuture in its list is not yet finished

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have 2 CompletableFutures. The **task2** should only start once **task1** finishes. Then, I need to wait for all tasks to finish. In my code below, the program ends after **task1** ends. The **task2** starts but did not finish. Any ideas why this happens? Also, why is it that the list only contains 1 entry while in the code, I added 2?

Code:

```
public void testFutures () throws Exception {
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    CompletableFuture<Void> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
      System.out.println(" task1 start");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(" task1 done");
      return null;

    });

    task1.whenComplete( (x, y) -> {
      CompletableFuture<Void> task2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
        System.out.println(" task2 start");
        try {
          Thread.sleep(2000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" task2 done");
        return null;
      });
      futures.add(task2);
    });
    futures.add(task1);
    // wait for the calls to finish
    try {
      CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()])).whenComplete( (x, y) -> {
        System.out.println(" all tasks done " + futures.size());
      }).get();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
 task1 start
 task1 done
 all tasks done 1
 task2 start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first clean your code.

Let's define a method that will do the sleeping, so that it does not muddy the water:

```
private static void sleep(int seconds) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Then let's separate the tasks and use proper methods:

```
private static CompletableFuture<Void> task1() {

    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println(" task1 start");
        sleep(5);
        System.out.println(" task1 done");
    });
}

private static CompletableFuture<Void> task2() {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println(" task2 start");
        sleep(2);
        System.out.println(" task2 done");
    });
}
```

You need to understand that chaining of `CompletableFuture` methods already do exactly what you want, they run the *next* stage, after the *previous* one has ended. You can make your code far, far more easy with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    testFutures();
}

private static void testFutures() throws Exception {

    CompletableFuture<Void> both = task1().thenCompose(ignoreMe -> task2());
    both.get();
    System.out.println("both done");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

First, you've created a race condition as to when `task2` gets added to your list of futures. At the time you execute this line—

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(...).get();
```

—which I'll call the *terminating getter*, you only have `task1` in the list. See for yourself by outputting its size:

```
// wait for the calls to finish
try {
    System.out.println("# of futures: " + futures.size()); // 1
```

`task2` still runs *eventually*, because you scheduled it with `whenComplete()`. But it's not your terminating getter that triggers it.

Recall that I said it's a race condition. To demonstrate this for yourself, add a `sleep()` before the terminating getter, like so:

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(6000L);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
// wait for the calls to finish
try {
    System.out.println("# of futures: " + futures.size()); // 2
```

Then you'll have given it enough time to add `task2`.

But here's the thing. *Now* is the terminating getter triggering both tasks?

*Still no!* And that's the second problem: You almost always want to use one of the `thenRun()`, `thenAccept()`, `thenApply()`, `thenCompose()` methods. These methods *chain* your futures, *i.e.* make each stage dependent on the previous, so that your terminating getter *actually* waits for the entire chain to complete. `whenComplete()` is a special method that kicks off a totally unrelated pipeline and is thus unaffected by the terminating `get()`.

In your case, you want to use `thenRun()`, like this:

```
    task1.thenRun( ignore -> {
```

Okay, so how do we combine all that?

```
public static void testFutures () throws Exception {
    
    CompletableFuture<Void> task1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> {
      System.out.println(" task1 start");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(" task1 done");
      return null;
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> futuresChain = task1.thenRun( () -> {
      System.out.println(" task2 start");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(2000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println(" task2 done");
    });
    
    // wait for the calls to finish
    try {
      futuresChain.thenRun( () -> {
        System.out.println(" all tasks done ");
      }).toCompletableFuture().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
 task1 start
 task1 done
 task2 start
 task2 done
 all tasks done
```

You see, you only need to `supplyAsync()` for the first task. You want to run `task2` sequentially after that task, so `thenRun()` will do the scheduling (the `supplyAsync()`ing) for you. So you don't need an array of futures either. The `allOf()` is for when you want to run tasks in **parallel**, and wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: this is _waaay_ too complicated for such a simple task.

Comment: @Eugene - Eh, my answer builds on the student's current understanding (even if imperfect). Your answer shows the ideal destination. Both are good to have.